# How to only load part of data in firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase database for my application, and basically people post new chapters of different series into the app.

So, I have one parent called "series" which hosts information about the different series: [image]

Then, I have one parent called "chapters" which contains many different children that are the different series keys, and under them are many chapters (so the chapters are under each series).[image: chapters]

However, I also want to have a section of the app where the user can view all newly added chapters across all different series, so I made a "latestReleases" parent, which automatically gets added to whenever a new chapter is added to "chapters." [image: latestReleases]

However, the way I am currently displaying latestReleases is to add the entirely of "latestReleases" to an array and then sort by date. Although with a small amount of chapters this works fine, there are now thousands of chapters, so there are thousands of things in latestReleases. Therefore, it takes literally forever for it to load. There must be a better way to do this, correct? I feel like a better way would be to only load part of the latestReleases, and then the user can choose to load more incrementally. However, it this possible? How else would I be able to achieve this? Would I need to create several "latestReleases" parents that get updated automatically? Thanks!

Comment: for example if you want to load in each time 10 chapters, add for each chapter new node and call it for example "section", for the first 10 chapters set the section to be 1 for the second 10 set it to 2 ....,when the user choose to load more chapter you can query the db with all chapters with section equal to 2

Comment: how would I do that? Every time a new chapter is added, how would that be handled?

Comment: you need to use multiple Queries in such case like Query inside a query will be a bit long process as you having multiple parents -> child Parent -> child

Comment: Add a new node to the root of your db and call it chapter count, when chapter added increase count and set section to be count/10 ( integer dividing)

Comment: Two things: Please include your Firebase Structure as a snippet of TEXT, no images or links. We can copy and paste text into an answer and it's also searchable and a LOT shorter. You can get your JSON via the Firebase Console->Three Dots on right->Export JSON. Second thing: Since you are sorting by dates, can you simply load the chapters you want via ref.queryStarting(atValue: start_date).queryEnding(atValue: end_date) or maybe even queryLimited(toFirst: 25) to get the first 25 chapters?

Comment: Jay, wow I didn't know you could do that! Is that in swift? Thanks so much, that sounds like a really good solution!

Comment: Hmm Mohamad that makes sense, if Jay's answer doesn't work out I will try that.

Comment: Jay, thank you so much, it worked perfectly (that was exactly what I wanted to do).

Comment: Awesome! If you need any more help I can whip up an answer with some code in it. Going forward make sure to include Firebase structures as text in your question instead of pics and also reference comments with @ in front of the persons name so they will be notified of your reply!